# Cognos HTML Output Generates multiple rows for each column

Tags: list, cognos-11

I have report that has 6 Query Calculation Columns in a List. Each column feeds from the same field 'Sale Number':

`IF( 'Metric 1' IN ?pCompany?)
THEN
(
CASE
WHEN ( [Metric] = 'Metric 1' ) THEN 
( count( distinct [Sale Number] FOR  [Metric], [Category] ))
END
)
ELSE
 ( 0 )`

Each of these columns have the Detail and Summary Aggregation set to `None`. Calculation is working fine. However, the report is generating each row for a column that has data in it. Like Below:
[image]

I tried changing the Detail and Summary aggregations to `Default, Total` But those options are adding the entire columns value into single cells and not consistent. 
Tried to Section and Group the Category field, but that just groups the Category name still repeating the no.of rows for each category.

Any idea on how to bring the output into single row for each category? I'm using Cognos 11.0.11 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just got lucky and figured out a solution. Updated the query to use `running-count` instead of `count`:

```
IF( 'Metric 1' IN ?pCompany?)
THEN
(
CASE
WHEN ( [Metric] = 'Metric 1' ) THEN 
( running-count( distinct [Sale Number] FOR  [Metric], [Category] ))
END
)
ELSE
( 0 )
```

And changed the `Detail Aggregation` to `Count Distinct` while `Summary Aggregation` set to `None`.

Got the output in a single row for each category. It doesn't work when I tried with only `Count Distinct` or `running-count`. It has to be a combination of both.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a crosstab.  Try simplifying the query item to this:

```
count( distinct [Sale Number] FOR  [Metric], [Category] )
```

...and using a crosstab.

Or you could break out that part of the logic into a separate query with [Category], [Metric], and count(distinct [Sale Number]), then join it to the rest of your data.  That would enable you to either use it in a crosstab, or to create a simpler expression for you "metric #" columns.

Comment: I cannot use the crosstab. There are few more calculations to be done and the crosstab doesn't support them. If I need just this then you're right crosstab is the perfect option. And, the query needs to be like that as I need the calculation only when that Metric is selected in the prompt